# Recursao implícita ao atribuir o retorno de uma função a uma variavel?

Tags: python, funções, recursão, return

Fala galera, estou iniciando estudos em Python e me deparei com um comportamento um pouco estranho para mim. É o seguinte: tenho um arquivo *teste.py* que contém algumas funções. Em um outro arquivo, *exempl1.py* importei este e outros arquivos como módulos. No arquivo *exempl1.py* criei uma 3 funções(*func1*, *func2*, *func3*). Na *func1* eu estou passando como parametros: uma lista e a referencia de uma função definida em *teste.py*.
Dentro de *func1* eu atribuí o retorno de *func2* a 3 variaveis, todas com os mesmos parametros para *func2*:

```
a = func2(x_best,h,0.1)
b = func2(x_best,h,0.1)
c = func2(x_best,h,0.1)
```

Entretanto, as variáveis estão recebendo os valores como se *func2* fosse executada 3 vezes, recebendo como parâmetros sempre seu proprio retorno da execução anterior. Outra coisa que percebi é que se eu declarar apenas duas variaveis, os valores atribuidos as variaveis é o equivalente a duas execuções da *func2* recebendo como parâmetros o retorno da execução anterior. Minha duvida é: está acontecendo uma recursão implicita de acordo com a quantidade de variaveis que eu declaro??? Estou bastante confuso com esses resultados.

Abaixo deixarei os codigos para que fique mais claro o que estou tentando falar. Vou omitir algumas funções pois elas não interferem no problema. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

**teste.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import json
from openpyxl import *
from random import *
from math import *

def beale ():
    return (1.5 - ponto[0]+ponto[0]*ponto[1])**2+(2.25-ponto[0]+ponto[0]*ponto[1]**2)**2+(2.625-ponto[0]+ponto[0]*ponto[1]**3)**2


def tgo(problema):

    pontos = points_generator(100)
    matriz = t_matriz_generator(pontos, problema)
    indices = list() 
    melhores = list()
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        j = 0
        while (j < 4):
            if(matriz[i][j] < 0):
                break
            if (j >= 3):
                indices.append(i)
            j += 1
    for a in indices:
        melhores.append(pontos[a])
    return melhores, problema
```

---

**exempl1.py**

```
from random import *
from teste import *
import math
import time

def LineSearch(Xtrial, Xbest, d, h):
    while (problema(Xtrial) < problema(Xbest)):
        Xbest = Xtrial
        h *= 2
        Xtrial[i]=trial_search(Xbest,h,d)
    return Xbest, h

def trial_search(ponto, h, d):
    FinalPoint = ponto
    for i in range(len(FinalPoint)):
        FinalPoint[i] = (FinalPoint[i]+h)*d
        if (problema(FinalPoint) < problema(ponto)):
            continue
        else:
            FinalPoint[i] = ponto[i]
    return FinalPoint

def Unirandi(x0, problema):
    tol = 0.0001
    h = 1.0
    fails = 0
    x_best = x0

    a = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)
    b = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)
    c = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)




p, problema = tgo(beale)
Unirandi([-0.05338583452963963, 4.311503781033389],problema)
```

---

Os valores para as variaveis são:

```
a -> [0.11094661416547036, 0.11531150378103339] 
b -> [0.11094661416547036, 0.11531150378103339] 
c -> [0.11094661416547036, 0.11531150378103339]
```

---

Se eu declarar apenas

```
a = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)
b = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)
```

como resultado eu tenho:

```
a -> [0.10946614165470361, 0.15311503781033392] 
b -> [0.10946614165470361, 0.15311503781033392]
```

e finalmente se eu declarar apenas

```
a = trial_search(x_best,h,0.1)
```

como resultado

```
a -> [0.09466141654703604, 0.531150378103339]
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está instanciando uma lista na chamada da função `Unirandi()` (a lista `[-0.05338583452963963, 4.311503781033389]`) e passando sempre a mesma instância para a função `trial_search()`. Como a função `trial_search()` modifica essa lista, ela vai sim modificar a mesma lista três vezes.

O que você pode fazer para resolver é duplicar a lista toda vez que for chamar a função `trial_search()`. Para duplicar uma lista basta fazer assim: `list(x_best)`. Nesse caso o código da função `Unirandi()` ficaria assim:

```py
def Unirandi(x0, problema):
    tol = 0.0001
    h = 1.0
    fails = 0
    x_best = x0

    a = trial_search(list(x_best),h,0.1)
    b = trial_search(list(x_best),h,0.1)
    c = trial_search(list(x_best),h,0.1)
```

Dessa forma as variáveis `a`, `b` e `c` ficarão com o mesmo valor `[0.09466141654703604, 0.531150378103339]`.